# Incompatibility between LuaLatex font feature and Graphite?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, directlua

when I use LuaLaTeX to modify my font (for example here kerning) at the same time as Graphite, there seems to be a problem because nothing happens. Everything seems to go well when I'm not using Graphite.

How can this be remedied? Is there an incompatibility between Graphite and `fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua{fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
name = "mykerning",
type = "kern",
data = {["I"] = {["I"] = -100,}}
}}

%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine G}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine G}[Renderer=Graphite]


\begin{document}


\Huge{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+mykerning} II} II

\end{document}
```

Comment: At least from the `fonspec` documentation, the Graphite renderer seems to be a XeTeX only feature.

Comment: @AlanMunn no since lualatex  use luahbtex it can use graphite, but then you can't use the lua code to manipulate the font (you should have heard Marcel's talk at tug ... ;-)).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good to know. So I guess the `fontspec` documentation needs a bit of an update.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So if I understand correctly, there's nothing we can do about it? :/